# Inject user data into json output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a friendship feature in my Rails/Angular app and currently I can create relations between users but I'm stuck on a small problem.

I have a `friendships` table,

```
create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

When a user adds another users as a friend a new record is created,

This is the index definition on the `friendships_controller`

```
def index
  friend = current_user.friendships
  render :json => friend.to_json()
end
```

And this is the json output.

```
{"id":1,"user_id":1,"friend_id":2,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:44.499Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:44.499Z"},
{"id":2,"user_id":1,"friend_id":3,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:45.463Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:45.463Z"},
{"id":3,"user_id":1,"friend_id":4,"created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:46.420Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:46.420Z"}
```

But this data is hardly usable. Is it possible to inject the user data in the friendship json?

```
{"id":1,"email":"peter@peter.nl","name":"Peter Boomsma"},
{"id":2,"email":"jan@jan.nl","name":"Jan Jansen"},
{"id":3,"email":"kees@kees.nl","name":"Kees Keesen"},
{"id":4,"email":"piet@piet.nl","name":"Piet Pietersen"}
```

So that the friendship json output looks like this,

```
{"id":1,"user_id":1,"friend_id":2,"email":"jan@jan.nl","name":"Jan Jansen","created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:44.499Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:44.499Z"},
{"id":2,"user_id":1,"friend_id":3,"email":"kees@kees.nl","name":"Kees Keesen","created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:45.463Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:45.463Z"},
{"id":3,"user_id":1,"friend_id":4,"email":"piet@piet.nl","name":"Piet Pietersen","created_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:46.420Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T13:18:46.420Z"}
```

*** REMOVE FUNCTION ***

```
app.factory('removeFriend', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    removeFriend: function(friend) {
    var _friendID =  parseInt(friend.id);
    console.log (_friendID)
    return $http.delete('/friendships/'+_friendID + '.json');
    }
  };
}])
```

This is the remove service in angular, here it passes the friend.id and not the friendship.id.

Comment: First use normal Rails methods to get the user data in the friendships. I'd also recommend only sending the data you actually need to the view layer.

Comment: @DaveNewton `First use normal Rails methods to get the user data in the friendships.` isn't that my question though? How do I merge the data?

Comment: I read your question as "how to I inject the data into JSON", not "how do I use Rails". My bad.

Comment: That's pretty snarky.

Comment: No, it's me mis-reading your question as being about something related to building JSON output instead of something related to Rails associations, e.g., http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. YMMV, but I tend to give people the benefit of the doubt instead of assuming the worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will implement something like following:

Add association in user model to get friends of the user i.e user objects

```
has_many :friends, through: :friendships, foreign_key: 'friend_id'
```

now get friends data in controller

```
friends = current_user.friends.as_json(:only => [:name, :email, :id])
render :json => friends # [{:name => 'test', :email => 'test@test.com', :id => 1},{...}]
```

If you need current user data in the response you can do something as following:

```
render :json => current_user.as_json(only: [:id, :name, :email]).merge(:friends => friends)
# {:id => 1, :name => 'user', :email => 'testuser@test.com', friends: [{:name => 'test', :email => 'test@test.com', :id => 1},{}]}
```

In above response you can send exact data required without repetition.

Comment: What is this magic! It's working, but how does rails know the data of the users? I can't see the connection. Is it because of the through friendships, friend_id ?

Comment: Try to run User.first.friendships and User.first.friends on console & check the sql generated by each command. You will see the connection!

Comment: I do have a follow up question though. I'm trying to create a remove friend function, but I can't target the friendship id since we are rendering friends. Any way around that?

Comment: You can send Id of the user you want to unfriend in API call. In backend find friendship Friendship.find_by(:user_id => current_user.id, :friend_id => ID_FROM_API_PARAMS) then deactivate / destroy the record.

Comment: Hm it looks like it's a problem in my Angular set up. I've editted my question, but I think this should be a different question.